# Is there such a thing as a finally with AngularJS $http?

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this:

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/api/Account/Register",
        data: {
            userName: userName,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword
        }
    })
    .success(function () {
        successCallback();
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        errorCallback(data);
    })
```

Is there any way that I could add in a finallyCallback to this with AngularJS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a `finally` method since 1.2.0rc1, as shown by the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#the-promise-api). The method was known as `always` since 1.1.5.

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/api/Account/Register",
        data: {
            userName: userName,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword
        }
    })
    .success(successCallback)
    .error(errorCallback)
    .finally(finallyCallback)
;
```

Answer (score 4):

The promise returned by `$http` is the same as any other promise created with the [`$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q). That means it will have a `finally` method:

```
$http({ /* ... */ })
.success(function () {})
.error(function () {})
.finally(function () {});
```

From the [`$http` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#usage):

> Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http specific methods